# bash prompt - exit meaning

Tags: bash, shell, exit, prompt

I am a beginner to bash and in general using shell. When I open a terminal, it comes up with a prompt like this:

```
myusername@dev94:~>
```

where myusername is in blue, dev94 is in red and > is in green (I understand that this color configuration is probably in my .bashrc file). Here is my question: When I type exit and hit enter, this happens:

```
myusername@dev94:~>
exit
exit
myusername@dev94:~>
```

The myusername@dev94:~> is all in black without any color. What is difference between the one in colors before I typed exit and the colorless one after I typed exit? 
(On a side note, I only typed the first exit. The second exit comes by itself when I hit enter. Wondering where the second exit is coming from. Is it just a bash/shell thing in every shell?)

If I type exit again (at the colorless prompt) and hit enter, then shell closes. I can understand this that the shell process quits and the window is closed. My 2nd question: 
Why didnt it close when I first typed exit at the colored prompt itself. Why did it go from the colored to the colorless prompt for the first exit command?

Thank you!

Comment: It almost sounds like your `.bashrc` (or `.profile`, etc) launches  a whole new shell... only way that behavior seems to make sense. Try `echo $$` before and after the `exit` command. That should tell you if it's the same process or not.

Comment: I agree with @FatalError

Comment: echo $$ prints out different process ids before an after the exit. I have a .bashrc file but no .profile file. I searched for the word exit in .bashrc to see if the command was configured to do something. But there is no exit word in .bashrc file

Comment: Do you have a .bash_profile or .bash_login? See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: Actually, @FatalError is saying you might find a line like `bash` or `$SHELL` in your .bashrc file.  Look for one of those rather than `exit`...

Comment: some terminal windows (like Putty) have an option like "don't close the window on exit". I think the blackened prompt is showing you that. Not sure about the extra exit, likely there is a shutdown file of some sort. Good luck.

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us your Linux distribution. Also, check the /etc/profile file, as that is the main "profile" for all users, even if you don't have ~/.profile. Also, check the PPID variable (`echo $PPID`), which should be the same as the second `$$` you get after `exit`'ing the first time.

Comment: Something is starting a new shell in your login process, and that new shell is being configured with colorful prompt - either the appropriate TERM variable is being set, or it's setting PS1 to a different value that includes the color escapes. When that shell exits, you're back to default. If there's terminal weirdness, that extra 'exit' could just be the shell echoing the command you typed back at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your shell sets a SHELL variable, but this isn't a must, and it is not necessarily correct:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

If you look with ps ax --forest at your process list:

```
ps ax --forest
```

you should find the ps command yourself, above that the inner Shell, above that the outer shell.

Comment: yes. echo $SHELL gives
/bin/csh
and ps ax --forest gives these above it
10013 pts/9  Ss  0:00 \_ -sh and 
10038 pts/9  S   0:00 |  \_ /bin/bash

and rightly so, when I type exit once and give echo $$, it gives 10013. 
This means, when I enter exit first, it goes into shell with PID 10013 right? 
So how is this related to /bin/csh which is the output whenever I type echo $SHELL in both the colored prompt and colorless prompt. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation is a bit more complicated, while your observations are right. On many systems, sh is a symbolic link to another shell - bash or dash for example. But that doesn't mean it behaves identical. Different config files are read or not, and the shell knows by reflection, how it was invoked, and turns syntax features off or on. But I would expect bash and csh to be bash and csh.

Comment: I think this may be particular to a shell distribution. because I am making these observations on a redhat system. On an ubuntu system, it just exits with the first exit. btw, echo $SHELL in redhat system gives /bin/csh whereas Ubuntu's shell gives /bin/bash. I think I am running csh on redhat system. Sorry if any confusion. And thanks for the illuminating discussion.

Comment: @user640639: Yes, that shell-in-a-shell thing isn't that common. I haven't seen it on any distribution - about 10 in 15 years.